# read nodes from yaml file

Tags: c#, .net, yaml

i have a yaml file that contains data related to particular device. i want to search for nodes, key/value pairs and retrieve values and then write them to oracle database. how to do that? here is examle:

```
---
-device:
   -printers:
       location: 176.12.43.11
       description: hp printer
```

i want to retrieve that data with similar below c# code:

```
YamlNode node = YamlNode.FromFile("C:\\test\\test.yaml");
YamlMapping mapping = new YamlMapping("device.printers.location");
var value = mapping.Value;
```

i've already searched for solutions, but didn't find any, there is not much info and detailed documentation about yaml.net . ahh yes, i wan't to retrive data to c# app.
there is .net library for yaml, that seems less documented and i didn't find solution to my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: I think this question is specific to yaml for .NET library you currently use. Hence it is necessary to mention what is it (and provide link to the website)

Comment: here is the link  http://yaml-net-parser.sourceforge.net/default.html